# Array Adapter not working correctly

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

I have an array that I'd like to add track listings to! It is quite simple but I am having quite a problem with my `ListView` and `ArrayAdapter` to work correctly. I have tried moving the `setAdapter` and the actual declaration of the `Adapter` but it doesn't work. To clarify, it works BUT I get the same songs about 800 times. I have tested my process of getting the title names and it works, but having a problem with the `ListView`

CODE:

```
ListView songList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);

TextView Test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

String fileType = ".mp3";

String[] myFile = new String[800];

File[] listFile = directory.listFiles();

adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myFile);

for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

    if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
        walkdir(listFile[i]);
    } else {
        if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(fileType)) {
            myFile[i] = listFile[i].getName().toString();
        }
    }
        songList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: It's repeated "about 800 times" because you hardcoded the size of the array to be 800.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use ArrayList instead of String[800]:

```
ArrayList<String> myFile = new ArrayList<String>;

File[] listFile = directory.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

    if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
        walkdir(listFile[i]);
    } else {
        if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(fileType)) {
            myFile.add(listFile[i].getName().toString());
        }
    }

}

adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myFile);

songList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I get `expected ( or [` at the end of the `new ArrayList<String>;` @geet

Comment: When I do this, my `ListView` goes empty.

Comment: so, it could be condition's issue.

Comment: I found the problem. It was because the `ArrayList` was being defined more than once and causing it to clear. I fix the problem. Thank you.